# How do I use the Codex Umbra as Maxwell?

Tags: dont-starve-together

When I choose Maxwell, I start with 6 nightmare fuel and the Codex Umbra, but I can't use the Codex Umbra to split my mind and create shadows; It just says examine. Why is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try throwing it on the ground and using it like a crafting station via his unique tab